# create a group of checkboxes with a click event associated Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a javascript function that builds a table with checkboxes.
I want associate a click event to them.
The event must be the same for all.

This is a part of my code:

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
    var tr = $(document.createElement('tr'));
    tr.addClass("MyBookings_table_content");
    $("#MyBookings_table").append(tr);

    //Create a CheckBox Element
    var chkbox = document.createElement('input');
    chkbox.type = "checkbox";
    chkbox.id = "chk"+i.toString();
    chkbox.name = "chk" + i.toString();
    //Event here
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you can simply add this event listener :

```
$("#MyBookings_table").on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", clickCB);

function clickCB() {
    var $cbx = $(this);

    // some code on my checkbox
}
```

This code is to be appended after the loop, see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6f79pd5y/

Comment: but If I do an alert window inside the click function to show the value of the combo box, a lot of windows open! And I just want one windows, because I only click on 1 checkbox.

Comment: Yes this code is to append after the loop (and not inside the loop)... I have added a fiddle if you want to see how to use it...

Comment: Another thing if you can help me again.
It's possible in click function add all checked checkboxes to an array ?
Thank you

Comment: Yes sure : use `$("#MyBookings_table").find("input:checked")`. But this is a jQuery object with all checked boxes. If you want an array with all DOM elements corresponding to the checked boxes, use instead : `$("#MyBookings_table").find("input:checked").toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

create a function and link it with an `addEventListener`

```
function outerFunction(){
}
checkbox.addEventListener('click', outerFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addEventListener("click",myFunction);
```

where you have the comments

Comment: It's working! thank you.
Is possible pass to "myFunction" the combobox object? something like addEventListener("click",myFunction(this)); ?

Comment: yeah,you have to do it a bit different though.addEventListener("click",function(e){ myFunction(this); }) Try this and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
    var tr = $(document.createElement('tr'));
    tr.addClass("MyBookings_table_content");
    $("#MyBookings_table").append(tr);

    //Create a CheckBox Element
    var chkbox = document.createElement('input');
    chkbox.type = "checkbox";
    chkbox.id = "chk"+i.toString();
    chkbox.name = "chk" + i.toString();

    //Event here
    $(chkbox).click(function()
                    {
                       alert("Click!"); 
                    });

    tr.append(chkbox);
}
```

A working example:http://jsfiddle.net/mpup12z5/

Answer (score 0):

If you reorganise your element-creation to use jQuery also, you can bind the click-handler at the point of creation:

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
    var tr = $(document.createElement('tr'));
    tr.addClass("MyBookings_table_content");
    $("#MyBookings_table").append(tr);

    $('<input />', {
        'type' : 'checkbox',
        'id' : chk + i, // i will be converted to a string automatically
        'name' : chk + i,
        'click' : functionToCall // note: no parentheses, you want to
    });                          // call the function, not use its return value
}
```

Or:

```
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
    var tr = $(document.createElement('tr'));
    tr.addClass("MyBookings_table_content");
    $("#MyBookings_table").append(tr);

    $('<input />', {
        'type' : 'checkbox',
        'id' : chk + i, // i will be converted to a string automatically
        'name' : chk + i,
        'on' : {
            'click' : functionToCall
        }                            
    });
}
```

But, it really is preferable to delegate the event-handling to the closest ancestor element, presumably the `<table>`, unless a specific property of the created `<input />` should call a different function, or do something somewhat different.